# USB3 not working after upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, usb-3, zenbook

I have Asus Zenbook Model UX31E-DH53. I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and USB3 stopped working. Any suggestions?

Comment: What you say "stopped working" what do you mean, stuff plugged in to those ports do not get detected or stuff plugged in to those ports run at 2.0 speeds?

Comment: Have you checked Asus website for updated Windows 10 USB 3.0 drivers?

Comment: @BillOer I've had a quick look on behalf of OP. ASUS does not support Windows 10 on his laptop and there are no Windows 10 drivers provided. The only thing OP has to go on is Windows' own drivers, either inbox or automatic via Windows Update.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop is a wee bit old. It utilizes Intel's 6-Series Chipset, which [does not include a native Intel USB 3.0 controller](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/usb3/sb/CS-033082.htm). Instead, your laptop has some 3rd-party USB 3.0 controller (often by Renesas Electronics, but I've heard of others).

ASUS [does not support](http://www.asus.com/nz/support/FAQ/1013416/) Windows 10 on your device, even though Microsoft may have offered you the free upgrade. That means some hardware features may not work or work well with Windows 10, and USB 3.0 might be one of those features.

Your best bet from here is to initiate a round of Windows Updates and see if the required USB 3.0 driver is installed automatically for you. If that fails, you can try uninstall the existing USB 3.0 devices in [Device Manager](https://s3.amazonaws.com/satisfaction-production/s3_images/613088/win7-device-manager-USB-3-Renesas.png) (sometimes they'll be shown as xHCI devices), reboot, and once again try Windows Updates.

Failing that, things get tricky and the answer is likely beyond the scope of a Q&A forum like SU. You'd then be best to engage the help of a computer geek who can sit down with you and troubleshoot.